# Flutter Listview can't scroll and not display all list

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview

i just started with flutter. in my case, i want to show 10 items listview on my home page. but that listview only shows 9 items. listview cannot be scrolled to show other item. can you see whats wrong with my code?

I have been looking for a solution to this problem by looking for a topic that has the same title, but nothing. i have changed some lines of my code but i get error "bottom overlow by 240px"

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

Future<Null> _fetchPartner() async {
  print('Please Wait');
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent),
    );
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: _fetchPartner,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(top: 18, bottom: 18),
                      child: Text("Powered By:",
                          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: 10,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Card(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          elevation: 0.4,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                              child: ListTile(
                                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                                      child: Image.network(
                                          "https://via.placeholder.com/150")),
                                  title: Text(
                                    "Coconut Oil",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black87,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Icon(Icons.linear_scale,
                                          color: Colors.greenAccent),
                                      Text("Go Green!",
                                          style:
                                              TextStyle(color: Colors.black87))
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                                      color: Colors.black87, size: 30.0))));
                    })
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below code Its working properly:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(top: 18, bottom: 18),
            child: Text(
              "Powered By:",
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
            elevation: 0.4,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
            ),
            child: Container(
              child: ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                    child:
                        Image.network("https://via.placeholder.com/150")),
                title: Text(
                  "Coconut Oil",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black87, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                subtitle: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.linear_scale, color: Colors.greenAccent),
                    Text(
                      "Go Green!",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                trailing: Icon(
                  Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                  color: Colors.black87,
                  size: 30.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

Your result screen:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add this property to `Listivew.Builder`

```
physics : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```

as it is inside `SingleChildScrollView`.

Comment: i try but not difference

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your code.

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    
    
    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }
    
    Future<Null> _fetchPartner() async {
      print('Please Wait');
    }
    
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
          SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent),
        );
        return Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
            body: RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: _fetchPartner,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding:
                              const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(top: 18, bottom: 18),
                          child: Text("Powered By:",
                              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    ListView.builder(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                         physics : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() 
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: 10,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Card(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              elevation: 0.4,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                              ),
                              child: Container(
                                  child: ListTile(
                                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                                          child: Image.network(
                                              "https://via.placeholder.com/150")),
                                      title: Text(
                                        "Coconut Oil",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black87,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                                      subtitle: Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Icon(Icons.linear_scale,
                                              color: Colors.greenAccent),
                                          Text("Go Green!",
                                              style:
                                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.black87))
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                                          color: Colors.black87, size: 30.0))));
                        })
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the singleChildScrollview and add a expanded widget on the listview.builder.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

Future<Null> _fetchPartner() async {
  print('Please Wait');
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent),
    );
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: _fetchPartner,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(top: 18, bottom: 18),
                      child: Text("Powered By:",
                          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                    Expanded(
                    
                    child : ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: 10,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Card(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          elevation: 0.4,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                              child: ListTile(
                                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                                      child: Image.network(
                                          "https://via.placeholder.com/150")),
                                  title: Text(
                                    "Coconut Oil",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black87,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Icon(Icons.linear_scale,
                                          color: Colors.greenAccent),
                                      Text("Go Green!",
                                          style:
                                              TextStyle(color: Colors.black87))
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                                      color: Colors.black87, size: 30.0))));
                    })
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try  with this code
replace your `body`  tag with this and let me know

```
Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          
          
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(top: 18, bottom: 18),
                child:
                    Text("Powered By:", style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
              )
            ],
          ) ,
         
         
             Expanded ( child : ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: 13,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Card(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        elevation: 0.4,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                            child: ListTile(
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                    child: Image.network(
                                        "")),
                                title: Text(
                                  "Coconut Oil",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black87,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                                subtitle: Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Icon(Icons.linear_scale,
                                        color: Colors.greenAccent),
                                    Text("Go Green!",
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87))
                                  ],
                                ),
                                trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                                    color: Colors.black87, size: 30.0))));
                  }) )
        
      ]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not convinced that any of the provided solutions is the right one. All of them use `shrinkWrap: true`. With only 10 elements this should not impact performance, but when it changes to 10k, well it will be a problem. I would simplify the tree by removing SingleChildScrollView and Column, moving Row from Column to ListView.builder, and displaying it only when the index == 0. We need to remember to add 1 in itemCount and remove shrinkWrap. There is another solution with the use of SliverList, but it would complicate too much without additional benefits. Below is the code for the first solution.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

Future<Null> _fetchPartner() async {
  print('Please Wait');
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: _fetchPartner,
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 10 + 1,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                if (index == 0) {
                  return Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                            top: 18, bottom: 18),
                        child: Text("Powered By:",
                            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                      )
                    ],
                  );
                }

                return Card(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    elevation: 0.4,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                        child: ListTile(
                            leading: CircleAvatar(
                                child: Image.network(
                                    "https://via.placeholder.com/150")),
                            title: Text(
                              "Coconut Oil",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black87,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            subtitle: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(Icons.linear_scale,
                                    color: Colors.greenAccent),
                                Text("Go Green!",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87))
                               ],
                            ),
                            trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                                color: Colors.black87, size: 30.0))));
              }),
        ));
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

"Replacing SingleChildScrollView widget with SizedBox should be sufficient."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).